# Why does my batch script fail to execute when run as administrator?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a windows batch script that will allow me to deploy preparation updates for Windows 7 64 bit but the script will not launch properly. I have all of the files inside of the same folder and I am attempting to extract the files then install them through dism when I launch it normally the files extract but dism does not launch correctly, when I run as administrator the files will not extract and dism exits with code 2. What am I doing wrong?

```
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3135445-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3135445-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3050265-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3050265-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3065987-v2-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3065987-v2-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3102810-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3102810-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3138612-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3138612-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3161608-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3161608-x64.cab 
expand -F:* .\Windows6.1-KB3161664-x64.msu .\ 
timeout 2
DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\Windows6.1-KB3161664-x64.cab 
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Run as administrator changes the current directory! Add these lines to prove it to yourself. Second line below will restore it for you. Delete the ECHO statements later.

```
echo %cd%
pushd %~dp0
echo %cd%
```

Also add this line at end:

```
popd
```

Comment: Where do I add the top line?

Comment: add the first 3 lines just above what you have shown in the code you posted

Comment: Ok great! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.