# Batch not launching exe when in Administrator mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I've got a simple exe application that writes in a file the first argument with which it gets called, so from command line I can do

```
MySimpleApp.exe "FOO"
```

and in the `SimpleFile.cfg` I get "FOO".
If I try to run this batch (it's in the same folder of the app)

```
set mypath=%~dp0
%mypath%MySimpleApp.exe "FOO1"
%mypath%MySimpleApp.exe "FOO2"
%mypath%MySimpleApp.exe "FOO3"
```

every time MySimpleApp gets called Windows ask the administrator permissions to execute the app. I thought that I could just run the batch as administrator, but even if I get no UAC prompt the application doesn't execute.
Is there some option or command that I must use to call an exe file when the batch is launched in administrator mode?

Comment: If you open a command prompt as Administrator and run the program from there instead of via the script, does it work? Also, this should have been handled by the `%mypath%` variable, but does the script work when you add `pushd %~dp0` to the start of the script?

Comment: No, starting the program from an Admin prompt doesn't work. But adding `pushd %~dp0` seems to fix this; if you want to add this as an answer I can mark it :)

Comment: I am very very confused as to how the program doesn't work from an Admin prompt, except for when it does. I'm also unclear on how the presence of `%mypath%` isn't already fixing your problem, but wild speculation is suggesting that your script has a space somewhere in its path. Is that accurate?

Comment: Both the script and the application are correct; the problems seems to be related to the fact that if I run the batch as Administrator it gets run from C:\Windows\System32 and the application is in another (virtual, actually) disk; Windows can't run the application for this reason, and calling `pushd %~dp0` changes the "working" drive of the prompt.

Comment: Yes, but using the full path to MySimpleApp.exe should have fixed that.

Comment: I tried also directly in a prompt (started in C:\) and if I call the app Windows asks me the Admin permission but then the application doesn't get executed. Maybe this is also explained by the fact that if I try to do `cd H:` from C:\ it doesn't work (while it does, for instance, using a Linux Bash)

Comment: `cd H:` fails because you're missing the `/d` flag.

Comment: Yeah, but I tried and I can't apply the /d flag when starting an application from another disk; so `pushd %~dp0` remains the correct solution.

Comment: See my answer here for explanation and example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378107/why-does-my-batch-script-fail-to-execute-when-run-as-administrator/38380916#38380916

Answer (score -1):

**Filenames with spaces MUST be enclosed in quotes.**

Always tack a `pause` at the end of a batch to see how it is interpreting your commands. And likewise if using `Echo Off` turn it on. Hiding information from yourself about YOUR error is not wise.

So

```
C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop>C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Desktop\MySimpleApp.exe "FOO3"
'C:\Users\FirstName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: This is not the problem, my paths don't contain spaces; in fact I don't get an error but the app is not executed correctly

Comment: It is one of your problems. Try your code as I did. AND I showed you the results.

Comment: I am not getting those errors; in fact, if I try typing the `PathToApp\MySimpleApp.exe "FOO1"` command directly in a prompt, I don't get any error, but the application is not executed correctly.

Comment: `%mypath%MySimpleApp.exe "FOO1"` in my case translates to `H:\Repos\NewProjectRepo\MySimpleApp.exe "FOO1"`, so there isn't this type of problem. The problem was instead the lack of `pushd %~dp0` at the beginning of the script. Maybe you have a different path/situation, but I have not that kind of problem. Also, as I said, the application appear to be executed properly, since I get no errors.