# My batch file for installing programs is crashing

Tags: batch-file, installation

I made this batch file intending to automate program installation between some Windows machines I constantly have to reformat, but when I run it, it just close the CMD without any error, I've tried many different things like BatCodeCheck but I wasn't able to find why it's crashing. I am **not** experienced with batch files so I am struggling really hard right now.

The idea behind my batch file is to have to run just one file and install all the basic software needed for the average Joe.

Here's my *AIO install everything.bat* file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

::##################################################################
:: Elevate this script                                             #
::##################################################################

(
    :: Check Admin rights and create VBS Script to elevate
    >nul fsutil dirty query %SYSTEMDRIVE% 2>&1 || (

        :: Very little red console
        mode con cols=80 lines=3 
        color cf

        :: Message
        title Please wait...
        echo[
        echo                         Requesting elevated shell...

        :: Create VBS script
        echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)>"%TEMP%\elevate.vbs"
        echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~f0", "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs", "", "runas", 1 >>"%TEMP%\elevate.vbs"
        if exist "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" start /b /wait >nul cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" 2>&1

        :: Delete elevation script if exist
        if exist "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" >nul del /f "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" 2>&1

        exit /b
    )    
)
pushd "%~dp0"
::##################################################################
:: Finished elevation                                              #
::##################################################################

set "javafolder=jre1.8.0_251"
set "java32installer=jre-8u251-windows-i586"
set "java64installer=jre-8u251-windows-x64"
set "winrar32installer=winrar-x32-590br"
set "winrar64installer=winrar-x64-590br"
set "libreoffice32installer=LibreOffice_6.4.3_Win_x86"
set "libreoffice64installer=LibreOffice_6.4.3_Win_x64"
set "chromesetup=ChromeSetup"
set "firefoxsetup=Firefox Installer"
set "klite=K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1544_Mega"

if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="AMD64" (
    set "PF86=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
    set "is64=1"
) ELSE (
    set "PF86=%ProgramFiles%"
    set "is64=0"
)

IF "%is64%"=="1" (
    set "nircmd=%CD%\nircmd64.exe"
) ELSE (
    set "nircmd=%CD%\nircmd32.exe"
)

REM --> Verifying dependances
IF NOT EXIST "%nircmd%" (
    echo Error
    goto END
)

REM --> Getting Windows version and saving in "windowsversion" variable
for /f "tokens=4-7 delims=[.] " %%i in ('ver') do (if %%i==Version (set windowsversion=%%j.%%k) else (set windowsversion=%%i.%%j))

REM --> Installing programs
IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR" (
    IF "%is64%"=="1" (
        start /d "%CD%" %winrar64installer%.exe -s
        %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %winrar64installer%.exe
    ) ELSE (
        start /d "%CD%" %winrar32installer%.exe -s
        %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %winrar32installer%.exe
    )
    IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR_goods.exe" start /d "%CD%" /wait cmd /c "winrar tweaks.bat"
    echo WinRAR installed
)

IF NOT EXIST "%PF86%\Google\Chrome" (
    start /d "%CD%" %chromesetup%.exe -silent -install
    %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %chromesetup%.exe
    echo Google Chrome installed
)

IF NOT EXIST "%PF86%\K-Lite Codec Pack" (
    start /d "%CD%" %klite%.exe -verysilent -norestart
    %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %klite%.exe
    echo K-Lite Codec Pack installed
)

IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox" (
    start /d "%CD%" "%firefoxsetup%.exe" -ms
    %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess "%firefoxsetup%.exe"
    echo Firefox installed
)

IF NOT EXIST "%PF86%\Java\%javafolder%" (
    start /d "%CD%" %java32installer%.exe
    %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %java32installer%.exe
    echo Java 32 bits installed
)

IF "%is64%"=="1" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Java\%javafolder%" (
        start /d "%CD%" %java64installer%.exe
        %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %java64installer%.exe
        echo Java 64 bits installed
    )
)

IF "%windowsversion%" NEQ "10.0" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\LibreOffice" (
        IF "%is64%"=="1" (
            %SystemRoot%\system32\msiexec.exe /i "%CD%\%libreoffice64installer%.msi" /QN
            %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %libreoffice64installer%.msi
        ) ELSE (
            %SystemRoot%\system32\msiexec.exe /i "%CD%\%libreoffice32installer%.msi" /QN
            %nircmd% cmdwait 200 waitprocess %libreoffice32installer%.msi
        )
        echo LibreOffice installed
    )
)

echo EVERYTHING WAS SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED!

:END
pause
endlocal
exit
```

If someone can point me where the error is, I would really appreciate it, thank you very much.

Comment: Turn `ECHO ON` and see what happens

Comment: First two rules of debugging a batch file. 1) Turn `ECHO ON`. 2) Run the batch file from a command prompt instead of executing it with your mouse.

Comment: @NekoMusume did it, fixed some bugs with starting and it works well when I start manually CMD as admin and run the batch script from it, but when I double click my bat and accept the UAC prompt, another CMD window pop for a second then disappear

Answer (score 0):

Run as Admin changes current directory. Check out the link below to prove it to yourself.

[Run as Admin changes current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378107/why-does-my-batch-script-fail-to-execute-when-run-as-administrator/38380916#38380916)

Comment: I changed the Run as Admin part and updated it in the main post, and it still closing before my eyes when I double click it, but it runs well if I run it from a previous opened admin CMD.

Comment: Add a few PAUSE statements to see how far you are getting.